# Pandas scatter_matrix - plot categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, kaggle

I am looking at the famous Titanic dataset from the Kaggle competition found here: http://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic-gettingStarted/data

I have loaded and processed the data using:

```
# import required libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# load the data from the file
df = pd.read_csv('./data/train.csv')

# import the scatter_matrix functionality
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix

# define colors list, to be used to plot survived either red (=0) or green (=1)
colors=['red','green']

# make a scatter plot
scatter_matrix(df,figsize=[20,20],marker='x',c=df.Survived.apply(lambda x:colors[x]))

df.info()
```

[image: scatter_matrix from matplotlib]

How can I add the categorical columns like Sex and Embarked to the plot?

Comment: A scatter plot is not a good choice for categorical variables, so it wouldn't really make sense to "add" those variables to this scatter matrix.  You could do a different set of plots involving those variables (for instance, boxplots of each numeric variable grouped by the categories).

Comment: BrenBarn - thanks.... I do not fully agree with you... when the factors are limited (like gender: male, female, unknown). I find it very insightfull to approach these like integers like 1,2 and 3 and plot these in  a scatterplot. If I remember correctly by heart, R treats its factors in a dataframe like this when plotting a scattermatrix. Was hoping could do the same with pandas.

Comment: i think you'll want to look at seaborn's facetgrids and pairgrids for this type of plot: http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html

Comment: Note that for pandas version >0.19, the `from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix` should be replaced by `from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix`(cf [reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102537/3047493) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to transform the categorical variables into numbers to plot them.

Example (assuming that the column 'Sex' is holding the gender data, with 'M' for males & 'F' for females)

```
df['Sex_int'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['Sex'] == 'M', 'Sex_int'] = 0
df.loc[df['Sex'] == 'F', 'Sex_int'] = 1
```

Now all females are represented by 0 & males by 1. Unknown genders (if there are any) will be ignored.

The rest of your code should process the updated dataframe nicely.

Answer (score 2):

after googling and remembering something like the .map() function I fixed it in the following way:

```
colors=['red','green'] # color codes for survived : 0=red or 1=green

# create mapping Series for gender so it can be plotted
gender = Series([0,1],index=['male','female'])    
df['gender']=df.Sex.map(gender)

# create mapping Series for Embarked so it can be plotted
embarked = Series([0,1,2,3],index=df.Embarked.unique())
df['embarked']=df.Embarked.map(embarked)

# add survived also back to the df
df['survived']=target
```

now I can plot it again...and drop the added columns afterwards.

thanks everyone for responding.....

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
# convert string column to category
df.Sex = df.Sex.astype('category')
# create additional column for its codes
df['Sex_code'] = df_clean.Sex.cat.codes
```