# Problems importing pandas.plotting

Tags: python, pandas

When I import pandas, everything is fine and working. Yet, when I try to import something from `pandas.plotting` im getting an error. What could be the source of this?

Here is how the output looks like:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named plotting
```

The pandas version Im using is: `0.19.2`

Comment: I reinstalled pandas package and got solved the issue!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks as though there has been some confusion around the movement of that module. The `plotting` module has been moved from `pandas.tools.plotting` to `pandas.plotting`. The difficulty is most likely stemming from the fact that as of version 0.19, the `pandas.plotting` library did not exist.

The current version is version 0.22. If you receive this error, the best practice is to update your version of pandas to the most recent version.

If, for some reason, you are unable to do this, the correct code for earlier versions of pandas would be

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

The correct code for current versions of pandas would be

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

Comment: In their defense the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) does refer to `pandas.plotting`.

Answer (score 11):

If you get this warning:

> **main**:1: FutureWarning: 'pandas.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix' is deprecated, import 'pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix' instead.

```
import pandas.plotting
```

or

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13579/files/fe8b918a7c7f322a6806d3b262b7b36bbd01da80#diff-52364fb643114f3349390ad6bcf24d8f

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that most cases when the errors come up on the import scatter_matrix, it is because you have not restarted your jupyter notebooks for a while.
Before I run the code;
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
I make sure I restart my jupyter notebook and run the code. Everything works just fine from then on.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this in importing scatter_matrix:

```
import pandas.plotting
# insert your scatter_matrix code here and run
# there should be no error messages (unless a new one)
```

To remove the array texts, you can put a ";" at the end of the code

```
import pandas.plotting
scatter_matrix(df, ...); #put the semi-colon here
```