# Problems importing pandas.plotting for building a scatter_matrix

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-matrix

This question is strongly related to this Question on Stackoverflow: [Problems importing pandas.plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102532/problems-importing-pandas-plotting)

I tried all the Answers, but this did not work.
So I also tried with and without the tools module

I also try to make a scatter_matrix:

[image]

My version of Pandas is: 0.24.2

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is the version of Python? For my py3.7, `from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix` worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix()
```

See doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

use:
`import pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix`

Reference document link for version 0.24.2
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html