# Scatter_Matrix Will Not Display Using Pandas and

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, data-science

Working through following the Machine Learning Tutorial:

http://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/

Specifically, Section 4.2. Unfortunately, my code is throwing an error

```
NameError: name 'scatter_matrix' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)
scatter_matrix(dataset)
plt.show()
```

There's at least one Stack Overflow question on scatter_matrix, but I haven't able to figure out what's missing.

[Pandas scatter_matrix - plot categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034424/pandas-scatter-matrix-plot-categorical-variables)

Comment: The question you link to even has the line `from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix` in it, you just forgot to copy it.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to import it like this:

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you've imported the Pandas. You could use it like below:

```
pd.scatter_matrix(dataset)
```

However, `pandas.scatter_matrix()` is deprecated. use `pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix()` instead